# How to divide the count() of two seperate queries in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

So I have

```
select count(*) from ( "query1") 

select count(*) from ( "query2")
```

I want to divide the two and get the floating point result.

I was told to use something like this

`SELECT (COUNT(smtg) * 1.0) / COUNT(smtg)`

But Im not sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do:

```
select q1.cnt * 1.0 / q2.cnt
from (select count(*) as cnt from ( "query1") ) q1 cross join
     (select count(*) as cnt from ( "query2") ) q2;
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
select ( (select count(*) from ( "query1")) * 1.0 /
         (select count(*) from ( "query2"))
       )
from sysibm.sysdummy1;
```

Answer (score 0):

other solution (be carefull to not divide by 0)

```
with 
query1 as (select count(*) as nb1 from ( "query1")), 
query2 as (select count(*) as nb2 from ( "query2"))

select case when nb2=0 then null else nb1* 1.0/nb2 end as Result
from query1, query2
```